# Why doesn't Perl recognize the file name?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to do a match file name with a document with an if condition, but Perl doesn't seems to catch it. I defined my document as:

`my $file = $filename`

Which `$filename` is equals to "/Desktop/src/file_top.sv". I'm running a program that reads the `$filename` and if the file is not named "file_top.sv", then the program doesn't create the other file (name is not relevant). I'm trying to do it with an if condition like this:

```
if($filename =~ /^file\_top.*\.sv$/){
   #do something....
}
```

But, it doesn't seem to work. Am I doing something wrong? Do you know any other alternatives? Should I use the whole path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not match because `^` means "start of the string", which in your case is the `/` character before `Desktop`.  Here is an approach to match just the file name without the directory path:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Basename qw(basename);

my $filename = "/Desktop/src/file_top.sv";

if (basename($filename) =~ /^file_top.*\.sv$/){
    print "do something....\n";
}
else {
    print "do something else....\n";
}
```

This will match filenames like `file_top.sv` and `file_top123.sv`, but it will not match `abc_file_top.sv`.